# OpenGL gimbal lock

Tags: opengl

I found example program about how to avoid gimbal lock:
http://www.mfwweb.com/OpenGL/Special_Rotations/Source.c
My question is how should function `void Render_Scene(void)` looks like if we have more than one object placed in vector or list? I used fragment of this code in my program but rotation doesn't work. I know there is some problem with matrixs. Here is my paintGL() function (I'm using qt):

```
void GLBox::paintGL()
{

glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT  | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

glLoadIdentity();

double *trans;
double *rot;
double *matrix;
double ang;
double **vertexes;

//camera
glTranslated(xTrans, yTrans, zTrans);
glRotated(xRot, 1, 0, 0);
glRotated(yRot, 0, 1, 0);
glRotated(zRot, 0, 0, 1);


for(unsigned int i = 0; i < vector_objects.size(); i++)
{
    glPushMatrix();

    trans = (*vector_objects[i]).getTranslation();
    rot = (*vector_objects[i]).getRotation();
    matrix = (*vector_objects[i]).getMatrixRotation();
    vertexes = (*vector_objects[i]).getVertexes_coordinates();
    ang = (*vector_objects[i]).getAngle();

    glTranslated(trans[0], trans[1], trans[2]);

    if (ang != 0.0)
    {
        //glLoadIdentity ();
        glRotatef (ang, rot[0], rot[1], rot[2]);
        glMultMatrixd(matrix);
        glGetDoublev(GL_MODELVIEW_MATRIX, matrix);
    }

    glMultMatrixd(matrix);

    //drawing
    for(int j = 0; j < (*vector_objects[i]).getNumber_of_vertexes(); j += 3)
    {
        glBegin(GL_TRIANGLES);
        glVertex3dv( vertexes[j]);
        glVertex3dv( vertexes[j + 1]);
        glVertex3dv( vertexes[j + 2]);
        glEnd();
    }

    glPopMatrix();
}

glFlush();
}
```

Do you maybe know how to fix this problem? Thanks for you help

Comment: *ARGH* that's exactly the kind of misuse OpenGL suffered ages. Please speak with me: OpenGL is not a matrix math library. This glGetDouble(GL_*_MATRIX, ...); ...; glMultMatrix crap is very, very bad style. Anyway the original author seems to have no clue about spatial transformation. The problem with Euler angles and gimbal lock is, that there is no clean solution to this problem using Euler angles. The only solution lies in not using Euler angles but a generalized way in storing rotations: Either rotation matrices or yet better Quarternions.

Comment: Thank you for clue about Quarternions. I'm reading about them right now.

Comment: A good example of using quaternions for this can be found [there](http://rainwarrior.thenoos.net/dragon/arcball.html)

Comment: Hah, wow, I've been using OpenGL since 1.0 was being developed, and it never once occurred to me to use it as a math lib. Coding horror, indeed.

Answer (score 1):

You really want to use quaternions for this. There are quite a few samples around. I've used [one from SGI](http://www.az.cs.is.nagoya-u.ac.jp/class/comp-sys/programs/trackball.c) (written by Gavin Bell) quite successfully. There are also libraries (e.g., [GLM](http://glm.g-truc.net/)) that include routines to manipulate/use them. Almost any decent book on the basics of computer graphics will have at least a chapter or two devoted to quaternion-based rotations as well.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. The link you gave is really useful. Thanks a lot.